# links with ui-sref does not display correct css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following template in angular. For some reason, the css is not making my link the correct hex code. However, if I take out `ui-sref="settings"` and replace it with `href="/settings"`, it works.

Has anyone had this sort of problem before?

**HTML**

```
<div id="settings-nav-left">
    <a ui-sref="settings" ui-sref-active="active">Account</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#settings-nav-left a { color: #439FE1; }
```

Comment: Try adding href="#" to the anchor tag?

Comment: ha, that worked thanks! is that a normal thing that needs to be done? @ChipDean

Comment: Yes, otherwise your browser will think it's a placeholder link. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an href attribute on all anchor tags otherwise it will be considered a placeholder link.
Try this:

```
<div id="settings-nav-left">
    <a ui-sref="settings" ui-sref-active="active" href="#">Account</a>
</div>
```